# SAML 2.0 best practices for custom user fields

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

We have an existing web application which works with its own users, stored in a local SQL server database and each user has specific rights to access specific content.

A new customer is interested in using this application, but their requirement was that it should have SAML 2.0 integrated.

Now, I'm new to SSO, but I assume they want this so all user management is done at their place and that their users can log on at any of their services, using the same credentials.

The user rights defined at our web application however, are application specific; they have no meaning outside our application. So I assume these fields should remain stored and managed at our end, instead of managed at the identity provider?

But what would be the best way initiate this? I could create an empty user record locally whenever the user logons for first time, but he would literally not be able to do anything without proper rights. I could give him default right settings, but there should be at least 1 administrator to distribute the rights of the remaining users. Is it common to ask additional fields at the identity provider to initiate users for a specific service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using entitlements sent in a SAML2 attribute. e.g. if you have a normal user profile for your application, you can ask the IdP to release an attribute such as `eduPersonEntitlement` or `urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.7` as it's known in SAML2. If the IdP owner agrees to release this attribute you can agree a controlled vocabulary with them for the value of the attribute.

So when a normal user logs in to your application using SAML2 and their attributes arrive in an `AttributeStatement` with a collection of SAML2 `Attribute` instances you can look for `urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.7`. If it has a value of, perhaps, `https://yourapp.com/entitlement/user` you can set them up with a normal user account. If they have a value of, perhaps, `https://yourapp.com/entitlement/admin`, you can set them up with admin rights.

Just be careful to compare what they already have (if anything) with their incoming SAML2 entitlement, in case they longer are an admin. The IdP decides who is a normal user and who is an admin but that's up to them to work that out. All you care about is the value of `urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.7`

The full set of eduPerson attributes is [here](http://software.internet2.edu/eduperson/internet2-mace-dir-eduperson-201602.html)